# Get events of some pages using appId+appSecret

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I'm trying to get events of some public pages making a request of this type:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100003078080509/events?access_token=appId|appSecret
```

I think that the procedure is correct, but I have no data returned. I've also tried a make this request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+APP_ID+"&client_secret="+APP_SECRET+"&grant_type=client_credentials
```

and then use the resulting accessToken but it's the same, no errors but no data.
If instead I use Graph API Explorer using a simple accessToken with basic permissions results are ok.

Why doesn't it work?

Thank you

Carlo